# Params with $state.go and $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I tried many things to pass data to my view, but i don't know what is wrong.
I tried with $scope and pass data with $state.go, but nothing happens.

```js
  .state('app.ler',
                            {
                                views: {
                                    'menuContent': {
                                        templateUrl: 'mensagens/mensagemRead.html',
                                        controller: 'MensagensCtrl',
                                        params: {'assunto': null}
                                    }
                               
                                },
                                url: '/ler'
                            })
  
     $scope.read = function (id) {
            MensagensService.ler(id).then(function (response) {
//                $scope.mensagem_ler = response.data[0];
//                alert(response.data[0].assunto);
                $state.go('app.ler', {assunto:response.data[0].assunto});
                console.log($stateParams);
            });
        };
```

```html
<ion-view title="Mensagens2">    
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="list">
            <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
                <img src="venkman.jpg">
                <h2>Gustavoaaa</h2>
                <!--<p>{{mensagem_ler.assunto}}</p>-->
<p>{{assunto}}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

`params` option of state is available in root level of `state` definition, you could not have them in leaf level of `namedView`.

```
.state('app.ler', {
     views: {
         'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: 'mensagens/mensagemRead.html',
             controller: 'MensagensCtrl',
         }
     },
     url: '/ler/{assunto}', //here is parameter mentioned in URL
     params: {
         'assunto': null //parameter default value
     }
 })
```

You can get this values in `$stateParams` object inside your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the state parameter using a `:` in the url of your state.

```
.state('app.ler',
    {
         views: {
             'menuContent': {
                  templateUrl: 'mensagens/mensagemRead.html',
                  controller: 'MensagensCtrl'
               }

         },
         url: '/ler/:assunto'
});
```

This will make the property `assunto` available in $stateParams

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your state configurations

```
url: '/ler?assunto'
```

If you want to pass more parameters then just add them like this

```
 url: '/ler?assunto&param2&param3....'
```

To use the state param in your view you can save it in a $scope variable in your controller and then use it.

For example: **$scope.assunto = $stateParams.assunto;**

```
<ion-view title="Mensagens2">    
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="list">
            <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
                <img src="venkman.jpg">
                <h2>Gustavoaaa</h2>
                <!--<p>{{mensagem_ler.assunto}}</p>-->
<p>{{assunto}}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: OK, but how can i get this value on my view? Thanks

Comment: bind it to a scope variable. In your controller do something like $scope.val = $stateParams.assunto and in your view template do {{ val }}. Make sure you injected the $stateParams dependency

Comment: Thanks @Vandervidi, i did exactly this and works. But i was thinking about a pog code. How about other functions inside my controller that needed set variables to. This kind variables apper like global. This is a best way to do this?

Comment: @GustavoMartins You welcome. Just configure whatever params you need in the state.url parameter like this : url: '/ler?assunto&param2&param3....'  If by some function  you want to pass to the state only param3 and not param2 then it will still work. Just remember to configure there all params that are used by all your controll functions. I dont know if this is the best way to do this. Im not familiar with another way.

Comment: @GustavoMartins Please accept my answer if it was helpful.